# Cloud run The user-provided container failed the configured startup probe checks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-run

I am following cloud run documentation https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks.
startup probe is failing and i dont see any useful information in logs.                                  Revision 'dev-xxxxxxxxxx' is not ready and cannot serve traffic.
The user-provided container failed the configured startup probe checks.                                                             anyone able to make it work??

tried to setup startup probe , but container failed to start

Comment: Can you share your service definition and the region where you deploy?

Comment: Please ignore this my syntax is wrong , I was using `--memory 2G --min-instances 1  --port 8082 ` instead  `--port=8082`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ignore this my syntax is wrong, I was using `--memory 2G --min-instances 1  --port 8082`  instead of `--port=8082`